# Why am I getting warnings about Xcode reading framework files from the remote iOS device during debugging?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory

I keep getting the following text coming up on my log after a few taps on my app. What is wrong and what do I need to do to fix it?

> warning: No copy of  found locally, reading from memory
>   on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
>
> warning: No copy of  found locally, reading from memory
>   on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
>
> warning: No copy of ImageIO.framework/ImageIO found locally, reading
>   from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your app. This message is your debugger telling you that it cannot find some framework code on your Mac. Instead it is reading it off the device which is rather slow. To solve this you could try reinstalling the iOS SDK.

Comment: very interesting to know, thank you very much for your answer. I shall reinstall my SDK :-)